# Вопрос об окончании существительного

Tags: грамматика, падежи, окончания

На данный момент документ находится *на исправлении*, или *на исправление*?

Answer (score 1):

*На данный момент документ находится (на чём?) на исправлениИ* — предложный падеж склонения существительных на **-ИЕ.**

Comment: Что-то слиплось, прописные в конце слова стоят, и смысл ускользает... Удивительно будет, если это поймёт Екатерина.

Answer (score 1):

1) Документ находится **на исправлении**  (П.п.). Окончание И для слов с основой на И.

2) Документ направлен **на исправление** (В.п). Окончание Е.